# Writing structure to an outputStream in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, struct, outputstream

I'm trying to pass a structure in a stream so that it is then sent over the socket to another device. The code works, but the wrong data is sent. And each time random data is sent - then I'm doing something wrong. Where am I wrong? Here is my code:

```
 public struct PStypes {
    var u: UInt32              //< [X_XXXXXX V]
    var i: UInt32              //< [X_XXXXXX A]
   }
 func sendMessage(message: String) {
    var task = PStypes(u: 7, i: 9)
    var bufferData = NSData(bytes: &task, length: 8)
    var data:Data = bufferData as Data
    var bufferDataSize = data.count                
    let bytesWritten = withUnsafePointer(to: &data) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: bufferDataSize) {
            outputStream.write($0, maxLength: bufferDataSize)
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this code:

```
let bytesWritten = withUnsafePointer(to: &data) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: bufferDataSize) {
        outputStream.write($0, maxLength: bufferDataSize)
    }
}
```

this ends up giving you a pointer to the `Data` data structure itself not the data it holds. You can fix this using:

```
let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    outputStream.write($0, maxLength: 8)
}
```

this also simplifies the code a little!

Answer (score 0):

var task = PStypes(u: 7, i: 9)

I think you are passing **Int** value instead of **UInt32**

Comment: Look at the definitions for the struct's "i" and "u" properties ... UInt32

Comment: Thank you.I did fixed. But that does not change